# How to fix the constructor in python

Tags: python, class, python-3.7

I know that in python the methods have parameter self called implicitly , In my code i cant access the constructor of my class.

```
class SmartFolder:

def _init_(self,path):
    self.path = path


path = "./temp/"
smart_folder = SmartFolder(path)
smart_folder.run()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "smart_folder.py", line 57, in <module>
smart_folder = SmartFolder(path)
TypeError: SmartFolder() takes no arguments
```

but i have a constructor which takes arguments.

Comment: are you sure that the indentations are correct?

Comment: This is _ _ init _ _ not _ init _ (double underscores)

Comment: It is invoking the default constructor which takes no arguments. Since your constructor doesn't match the proper constructor name as pointed out by @Francky_V, the constructor you defined will function just as a normal function not as a constructor.

Comment: I think what @Francky_V is trying to say is you need to use ```__init__``` with two underscores preceding and succeeding the word init.

Comment: @LazyCoder Absolutely

Answer (score 0):

Please check the indentations and code format. Hope this helps.

```py
class SmartFolder:
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = path

    def run(self):
        #Your code here
        pass

path = "./temp/"
smart_folder = SmartFolder(path)
smart_folder.run()
```